# Some blender newbie problems

Tags: modeling, sculpting

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YuVJ7lP5Sfc&t

At the beginning of the video you can see that he adds a lot meshes.

How does he do that so fast? Because when I add two objects and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> and try to sculpt, they do appear as one object but I still got some sculpting bugs (they cant fully "Connect").

In another section of the video (0:10), he somehow paints exactly on the mesh and turns it into a 3D object (the shoulder armor) and then adds a cylinder there.

Similar examples (1:48)

Comment: Please put some effort into communicating your question better. Be specific. Most likely, you will not get help with "some sculpting bugs" for example because there is no way to tell what you mean by that. You should explain in detail.

Comment: I dont know how to explain it more then i did already... i got many qustions in my topic. But i will try again i guess... when i join 2 mashes and then try to smooth them together (after pressing Ctrl + J ) i still cant smooth them fully in the "connecting" points.

Comment: I understand that English is not your native language, but you can still put some effort in communicating in full sentences and use some sort of spell checker add-on for your web browser. That would make it a bit easier to read and understand. I attempted to answer. I hope that helps.

Comment: Patience and tolerance is not your strong side ;D still Ty for trying i guess some else will understand what im talking about

Comment: I am sorry for being so direct, but it really helps to get better answers not just from myself. It's an honest advise despite it possibly sounding a bit rude. It's surprising just how much effort and time people put into answering questions here sometimes. I think it's always a good idea to encourage that by doing the same with asking the questions.

Comment: Hi. Please make the title of your question specific to the problem you are having and not just the general topic. Also, please only ask one question at a time. You are welcome to ask multiple questions but as separate posts. I suggest editing your question down to just one question (by using the [edit] link below it) and asking the other one separately. Thanks.

Comment: Ctrl-J joins two objects, but their geometry remains independent. It's almost like it's really only grouping the objects rather than melding them together. So when you find that you can't smooth them where they intersect one another, this is why. They would have to have their vertices merged after being joined. Then your smoothing effort would behave  more like what you expect.

Comment: K got it, so how u do join 2 objects so u can sculpt them as u wish ( if Ctrl + J is not the best option)

Comment: Ctrl+J is the only option. If you join them with Ctrl+J and use re-meshing from Data tab in the Properties Editor, it will create a continuous surface.

Answer (score 2):

He is probably duplicating some objects with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> in the beginning. You can also add objects quickly with keyboard - for example pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> followed by <kbd>M</kbd> and <kbd>M</kbd> one more time will go through Add Menu then Mesh and then Monkey, you can type that quite fast. You can see the letters coresponding to the menu items in the menus underlined:

[image]

It's possible to create custom shortcuts for something that you do a lot as well.

If the object is constructed out of a lot of objects joined in sculpting, some sort of re-meshing is usually used to make a continuous surface that you can sculpt:

[image]

Comment: TY :)  but do you know what he does  in the 0:10 sec of thw video ? He somehow paints exactly on the mesh and turning it into 3D object [ the shoulder armor ] and then adding cylinder there.

Comment: I think this time-lapse is not the best material to learn from. I guess he might have some shortcut to add a single vertex mesh(like I do myself) or maybe he tabs into some objects edit mode and then duplicates a vertex that is later snapped to place and extruded to mouse position with ctrl + right clicking, it is possible to keep it on surface with snapping on and set to faces. It's hard to guess what exact functions he is using because it's sped up so much.

Comment: Its called Retopology. Usually used for creating a low poly model from a high poly model so that it can be used in games. But here he is using it to create the shoulder armor. He has snapping to surface enabled so that what ever he adds sticks to the surface or the  modlel below. He Starts by adding a single vertex and by extruding from this he traces out the outline of the shoulder armor. Then he fills in the the faces and probably using a Solidify modifier to give it thickness.

Comment: Blender has a steep learning curve and you have to learn the basics before attempting anything the least bit complicated otherwise everything else that follows becomes more and more frustrating.  Here is a link to a quick tutorial on Retopology but will not very  usefull to you if you are only starting out with Blender. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U3sY3f6aKB8

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, to work at such speeds typically requires practice imo. It appears that the sculptor was also constantly adding meshes to the model. I believe the method is to not worry about clipping (or the need to join meshes), and always be refining and reshaping it.


Just my 2 cents, but hopefully this should get the ball rolling for when the real answers come along.


Cheers.